# How to Set repeat interval as well as fire date in UNNotificationRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

Previously I am using `UILocalNotification` for reminder purpose in my application.

But as above API is deprecated in iOS 10.0 now need to use UserNotifications Framework's `UNNotificationRequest`.

Using `UILocalNotification` i was able to set fire date as well as repeat interval as below:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    localNotification.fireDate = tomorrow;


    if(repeatUnit!=0){
          localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

In above code I'm able to set tomorrows date when notification will get fire and also i was setting repeat interval of 1 week which is going to be started from fire date.

How this could be achieved using UserNotifications Framework's `UNNotificationRequest`.

Because in new api we can use either of trigger `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and `UNTimeintervalNotificationTrigger` to initiate `UNNotificationRequest`.

Is any way available so set both just like `UILocalNotification` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use the fire date and a repeat interval but it is not as obvious as it used to be. When you initialize the notification trigger you set its repeat parameter to `YES`. The repeat interval is defined by the date components that you pass to the trigger via the `dateMatching` parameter:

**Repeat daily:**
Just pass the date components **hour**, **minute**, **second**
⟶ The trigger will fire every day at that time

**Repeat weekly:**
Also pass the desired weekday component: **weekday**, **hour**, **minute**, **second**
⟶ The trigger will fire every week on that weekday at that time

Here is an example that fires a notification tomorrow at the same time and repeats it every week:

**Objective-C:**

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *notification = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];

// find out what weekday is tomorrow
NSDate *sameTimeTomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24];
NSInteger weekdayTomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate: sameTimeTomorrow];

// set the current time (without weekday)
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute |  NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSDateComponents *firstFireDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:sameTimeTomorrow];

// add tomorrow's weekday
firstFireDateComponents.weekday = weekdayTomorrow;

// set a repeating trigger for the current time and tomorrow's weekday
// (trigger repeats every week on that weekday at the current time)
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *notificationTrigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:firstFireDateComponents repeats:YES];

UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"notification" content:notification trigger:notificationTrigger];
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler: nil];
```

**Swift:**

```
let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()

// find out what weekday is tomorrow
let weekDayTomorrow = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24))

// set the current time (without weekday)
var firstFireDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())

// add tomorrow's weekday
firstFireDateComponents.weekday = weekDayTomorrow

// set a repeating trigger for the current time and tomorrow's weekday
// (trigger repeats every week on that weekday at the current time)
let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: firstFireDateComponents, repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Comment: I think it should also be noted it's not possible to set both `fireDate` and `repeatInterval` in a manner that would say “schedule a notification firing every minute starting three hours from now”. 

Comment: nide @joern, can you please give me an example of bi-weekly repeating notification example ?