# Repeat alarm every day in Xamarin Forms in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to repeat an alarm everyday at same time in my Xamarin Forms. However the iOS version doesn't repeat but it only occurs once at the specified date & time. I am converting DateTime to NSPDateComponents and passing it to UNCalendarNotificationTrigger to create the alert. The Datetime value is correct, but the repeat is not working.

```
public static NSDateComponents ToNSDateComponents(this DateTime dt)
{
  var d = new NSDateComponents
  {
     Hour = dt.Hour,
     Minute = dt.Minute,
     Second = dt.Second,
     Month = dt.Month,
     Year = dt.Year,
     Day = dt.Day,
     TimeZone = NSTimeZone.SystemTimeZone
  };
  return d;
}

// notifyDate returns (e.g 16/11/2020 10:00 so I want the alarm to repeat every day at 10:00)
var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(notifyDate.ToNSDateComponents(), true);
var requestID = "request_" + id;
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) => {
if (err != null){
}
});
```

Comment: If you want a daily notification, you must only set the hour/min/sec of the `NSDateComponents`, you are hardcoding a "full date".

Comment: I will give it a try, but never thought it would be that easy.

Comment: Found ObjC/Swift examples w/ context for daily/weekly repeats https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237351/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover If you are submitting an answer, please do so otherwise, I will accept what has been added as answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a special date, therefore it only can repeat once.

Here is the sample to repeat an alarm everyday at **09:30**, you could have a look:

```
// 1
var dateComponents = new NSDateComponents();
dateComponents.Hour = 9;
dateComponents.Minute = 30;
var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(dateComponents, true);

// 2
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
content.Title = "Daily reminder";
content.Body = "Enjoy your day!";

var requestID = "request_" + id;
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

// 3
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) => {
    if (err != null)
    {
    }
});
```